# Dynamic typings in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Let's say I have 3 packages (package A, B and C) and all them are published separately to NPM.

Package **A** contains **React components**, and for the component props typings, package **A** is importing `types` from package **B**.

```js
// Package A

import { HeaderProps } from '@package/b'

export const Header: React.FC<HeaderProps> = (props) => <HeaderComponent {...props} />
```

Package **C** also contain the props typings for the components in package **A**.

**Question:** How con I change (or update) the props of header from package **C**? (after I import pakcage **C**, the props of Header should be changed automatically)

I tried using **module declaration** but it was throwing some errors.

Comment: `the props of Header should be changed automatically`  What do you mean?,  if package A & B get changed then there version should also change, and a npm update on C will get the new declarations.

Comment: @Keith suppose, i install package C, then the package A should take props from package C and not B

Comment: You can't do that!, from what I can gather your trying to create some sort of plugin system.  In that case you might want to look into `interface`'s, and a form of registration process.

Comment: @Keith yes, it's kind of plugin system, what do you mean by registration process?

Comment: I'll see if I can knock up a really simple example.

Comment: @Keith yea, that would be really helpful and thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your creating a plugin system, Typescript has a nice feature called interfaces, you could also use classes, but it's not required.

So for a simply example let's create a simple plugin that simply has a `hello` method.

First we need to create some sort of plugin manager, here we can store the expected interface the plugin will need, and also some place to register said plugin.

```
//plugin.ts

interface MyPlugin {
  hello: () => void
}

interface Settings {
  plugin?: MyPlugin
}

export const settings:Settings = {
} 

export function plugin() {
  if (!settings.plugin)
    throw new Error('No plugin registered');
  return settings.plugin;
}
```

Nothing too complicated here, we have a simple `interface` that our plugins will need to implement, a settings structure to store the current plugin.  And a simple utility function to get the current plugin and throw an error if one not yet registered.

For demo purposes I'm just using separate files, but these files could be in different NPM repo's, Javascript doesn't care..

So next, let's create our first plugin.

```
//plugin-a.ts

import {settings} from "./plugin";

settings.plugin = {
  hello: () => console.log('plugin A');
}
```

We can do the same for our next plugin.

```
//plugin-b.ts

import {settings} from "./plugin";

settings.plugin = {
  hello: () => console.log('Another plugin B');
}
```

Finally let's use our plugins.

```
import "./plugin-a"; 

import {plugin} from "./plugin";

plugin().hello();
```

In the above if we change the `./plugin-a` to `./plugin-b`, everything will just work with the new plugin.

You could now easily extend your plugin later to have a `bye` method and Typescript is going to automatically let you know what needs implementing in `plugin-a` & `plugin-b`.

Of course this is a very simple plugin system, you might have a plugin system were you can register multiple plugins, here an array of plugins could be kept.  To clean things up, it might also be an idea to have a `register` function instead of using `settings.plugin =` etc.  But I've deliberately kept this as simple as possible for people to follow.